# how to submit a select option without javascript?

Tags: html, forms, html5-canvas

I have this but for some reasons the seller_email input is not submitting. Let me know what is wrong and how can I fix it . Of course without javascript.

```
<form name="input" action="mail.php" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<select name="seller_email" form="input">
<option value='hello@example.com'>hello@example.com</option>
</select>
 Address: <input type="text" name="bank_address"><br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when you say it's not working what error do you get?

Comment: the option "seller_email" is not submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `form="input"` in your select box. I'd also stay away from naming form's something like input, which could be a reserved word.

```
<form name="myForm" action="mail.php" method="post">
 name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 <select name="seller_email">
  <option value='hello@example.com'>hello@example.com</option>
 </select>
 Address: <input type="text" name="bank_address"><br>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you don't need the `form="input"` in your `select` option

Comment: thanks for your patience... I don't know where I've seen that (form on select)